# Plone 4.0.4 and Postgresql Encoding

Tags: postgresql, encoding, plone, zodb

Im using Plone 4.0.4, Postgresql 9.0.3 and RelStorage 1.5.0b2. Currently Im using "da_DK.ISO8859-1" encoding in PostgreSQL - would "da_DK.UTF-8" be better since Plone is using UTF-8 internally? PS both "Encoding, Collation and Ctype" are set in Postgresql.

Thanks.
Nikolaj G.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RelStorage stores only Python pickles in BLOBs, the rest is transaction metadata in the form of integers and boolean flags. At no time will you see raw object contents appear in the database and there are no character columns in the RelStorage schema.

As such, it makes no difference whatsoever what encoding you use for PostgreSQL.